# Why do I get Type Error when passing props in map?

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to pass the 'name' prop to the component  without a type error. I have an array of objects being passed in as {reslist} and each object in that array has a logo, and name value. I cant seem to pass name or logo into my return.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Resources.css'
import CodeCard from '../CodeCard/CodeCard.js'

const Resources = ({ reslist }) => {
    return (

        <div>
            <h3 className='resCall'>Check out my Code!</h3>
            <div className='resCards'>
                { reslist.map((i) => {
                        return ( <CodeCard 
                        key={i}
                        name={reslist[i].name}


                        />
                        );
                })


                }
            </div>

        </div>
        )
}

export default Resources;
```

Here is the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (anonymous
>   function)

Here is my Resource List

```
const ResList = [
{
    logo: 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
    name:'GitHub'
},
{
    logo: 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
    name:'GitHub'
},
{
    logo: 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
    name:'GitHub'
},
{
    logo: 'https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png',
    name:'GitHub'
},


]

export default ResList
```

Comment: Can you show us what `reslist` is?

Comment: I added it, also to note when I console.log the the last that's getting passed it logs just fine

Comment: I am assuming name is inside the object returned by iterative array. You should be using `i.name` instead of `reslist[i].name`. `map` function returns iterative value as first paramter instead of index; index is second parameter.

Comment: `import CodeCard` should be `import { CodeCard } `? edit it with `import { CodeCard } from '../CodeCard'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map callback has incorrect parameters. The first parameter is value, 2nd is index ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
reslist.map((value, index) => {
  return (<CodeCard 
      key={index}
      name={reslist[index].name}
  />)
})
```

But of course, you can use `value` directly too:

```
reslist.map((value, index) => {
  return (<CodeCard 
      key={index}
      name={value.name}
  />)
})
```

Comment: Gotcha, I need to pass another parameter along with the index. This worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `reslist` is an array of objects.  When you call `.map` on an array of objects, the first parameter (in your example, `i`) is each object.  The second parameter is the index.  I think you're getting these two mixed up.

```
reslist.map((item, i) => (
    <CodeCard
        key={i}
        name={item.name}
    />
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing components don't need to have `.js`:
edit it with `import { CodeCard } from '../CodeCard'`
ps: please don't shot me